# c++, How to transverse a linked list while deleting duplicates

Tags: c++, linked-list

The problem: I have a .txt file that contains multiple numbers and I need to put these numbers in order as well as delete any duplicates. I have made the function for putting them in order (it works). and I am currently working on the deletion process.

I am not sure how to make it so that it will run through the whole list. Because if the first two numbers are 0, it will only delete the first one and then the function ends.

Anyway, this is what I have so far for my delete function:

```
void deleteDuplicate(Node*& head) // head is the list with the ordered numbers
{
  Node* tmpPtr;
  Node* delPtr;

  if (head == nullptr){
    return;
  }else if (head->data == head->next->data){
    delPtr = head;
    head = head->next;
    delete delPtr;
  }else{
    tmpPtr = head;
    delPtr = head->next;

    while (delPtr != nullptr && delPtr->data != delPtr->next->data){
      delPtr = delPtr->next;
      tmpPtr = tmpPtr->next;
    }
    if (delPtr != nullptr){
      tmpPtr->next = delPtr->next;
      head = head->next;
      delete delPtr;
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Are you allowed to simply not insert the duplicates?

Comment: Looking at this from another side, you probably don't want to implement the function this way. Odds are good you have a remove function that you have already tested and know works. If you don't consider making and testing one. Just iterate once and call the pre-existing remove function for each node you want removed.

Comment: Mind you, that leads to the question, "How do I know which nodes I want to remove?" I find `std::set` works very well for this. Every time you see a node, check if its value is in the set. If in the set, remove from list. If not in set, add the value to the set.

Comment: Why not filtering "duplicates" during the insertion by adding only new nodes different from present ones ? The sort function could be `if (new_node->data < curr_node->key) { ... } else if (new_node->data > curr_node->key) { ... } else { delete new_node; // duplicate }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the provided source code, the function `deleteDuplicate()` reveals two missing details in the analysis. By choosing to delete the first node in case of duplicates, it is necessary to update the link to the first node.

> Instead of deleting first node, in a linked list, it is easier to
>   delete the second node by routing the first node to the third node.

**Missing Analysis 1** - the second if-condition has to be merge with the general condition.

The case `if (head->data == head->next->data)` could be merged by deleting the node `head->next` instead of the node `head`.

Just remove the second if-condition:

```
if (head == nullptr){
    return;
}
// to be managed in the else condition
//else if (head->data == head->next->data){
//  delPtr = head;
//  head = head->next;
//  delete delPtr;
//}
else{
```

**Missing Analysis 2** - delete the second node in all cases of duplicates.

> To delete the second node, compare both `tmpPtr->data` and
>   `delPtr->data` instead of `delPtr` and `delPtr->next`.

Replace the following while-loop:

```
while (delPtr != nullptr && delPtr->data != delPtr->next->data){
    delPtr = delPtr->next;
    tmpPtr = tmpPtr->next;
}
```

By a strong solution while-loop:

```
while ((tmpPtr != nullptr) && (delPtr != nullptr)
        && (tmpPtr->data != delPtr->data)){
    delPtr = delPtr->next;
    tmpPtr = tmpPtr->next;
}
```

Then in the deletion, don't change the `head` node:

```
if (delPtr != nullptr){
    tmpPtr->next = delPtr->next;
    // not needed when deleting the second node
    //head = head->next;
    delete delPtr;
}
```

**Bonus** - adding a do-while to explore all the linked list, one call of `deleteDuplicate()` allows to delete all duplicates !!!

Here is the complete `deleteDuplicate()` function:

```
void deleteDuplicate(Node*& head)
{
    Node* tmpPtr;
    Node* delPtr;

    if (head == nullptr){
        return;
    }
    else{
        do {
            tmpPtr = head;
            delPtr = head->next;

            while ((tmpPtr != nullptr) && (delPtr != nullptr)
                    && (tmpPtr->data != delPtr->data)){
                delPtr = delPtr->next;
                tmpPtr = tmpPtr->next;
            }
            if (delPtr != nullptr){
                tmpPtr->next = delPtr->next;
                delete delPtr;
            }
            // explore all the linked list
        } while (delPtr!=nullptr);
    }
}
```